# Can a node take early action on a schedulable state?

Tags: corda

Assume there's an `ObligationState` with a deadline that will expire automatically at time `t`.

1. Can a node settle the obligation early before the deadline? Does that consume the state and destroy the `scheduledActivity`?
2. If the `scheduledFlow` can only be run by one side of the party, If that node maliciously shuts down and time passes `t`, when it restarts, what would happen to the state?

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes. A node can settle the obligation early and you're right in your assumption that the state is indeed consumed and the scheduled activity destroyed.

2) In theory, when the node restarts, it should process any scheduled activities that are past time t and have not run. This would make for a really interesting test, one I might do.